# How can I get documents with some conditions?

Tags: mongodb, match

I have some objects:

```
var array = [];

var obj1 = new Object();
obj1.category = 0;
obj1.sequence = 0;
obj1.otherAttr = 1;
array.push(obj1)

var obj2 = new Object();
obj2.category = 1;
obj2.sequence = 2;
obj1.otherAttr = 2;
array.push(obj2)

var obj3 = new Object();
obj3.category = 4;
obj4.sequence = 3;
obj1.otherAttr = 3;
array.push(obj3)
```

...

and I have collection in MongoDB:

```
{
    category:0,
    sequence:0,
    anotherAttr:1
},
{
    category:0,
    sequence:1,
    anotherAttr:2
},
{
    category:0,
    sequence:2,
    anotherAttr:3
},
{
    category:1,
    sequence:0,
    anotherAttr:4
},
{
    category:1,
    sequence:1,
    anotherAttr:5
},
{
    category:1,
    sequence:2,
    anotherAttr:6
},
...
```

I wanna insert these objects. But Before insert these, I want check overlapping **category** and **sequence** between these and document in MongoDB unrelated to otherAttr or anotherAttr. For example, I have objects like top, the result I need is :

```
{
    category:0,
    sequence:0,
    anotherAttr:1
},
{
    category:1,
    sequence:1,
    anotherAttr:5
}
```

I tried to `$match`. But can't check some conditions in many attributes.

Comment: Your condition is not very clear. Could you specify?

Comment: @Webdev I want the documents with (category=0 and sequence=0(obj1)) or (category=1 and sequence=1(obj2)) or (category=4 and sequence=3(obj3)). I hope you understand my explanation.